# How to include static library based on CMAKE generator

Tags: lua, cmake

I'm trying to add lua static library onto my project using CMAKE. But what I found from lua documents that they have several version of Visual Studio libraries for 32/64-bit architecture.

I need to learn is there a option on CMAKE to identify the architecture and generator used for generating required files.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a host of [system inspection variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-describe-the-system) and [information variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-provide-information) which CMake offers. I'll try to list some which might be applicable in your case:

- [`CMAKE_CL_64`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CL_64.html): true if the compiler being used is Microsoft's CL targetting a 64-bit architecture
- [`MSVC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MSVC.html): true if using a Miscrosoft Visual C++ compiler
- [`CMAKE_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html): the generator being used
- [`CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM.html): generator-specific target platform name
- [`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html): size of `void*`, in bytes

You should also be aware that CMake ships with a [FindLua](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLua.html) module, so you might find the decision already implemented for you in that module. (I have never used it myself, so I do not now whether/how it works).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me huge